# Marketo REST API: Associating a lead with a program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, marketo

I've searched high and low and don't believe this is possible, but before giving up, thought I'd ask on here. Is there any way that anyone's found - roundabout or not - to create a lead and associate it with a program in Marketo via their REST API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a smart campaign that automatically associate leads with the relevant program?

You can create some custom field in MLM (for example: "Associate with Program") and when you create a new lead with the API add some value in this field, i.e "associateWithProgram" : "program123".

Then, in MLM create a campaign that is being triggered whenever a new lead is created and the associateWithProgram field is not empty.

The flow will be to add the lead to the desired program.

Answer (score 0):

```
   curl -X POST \
  "${baseUrl}rest/v1/leads.json?access_token=${AccessToken}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '
{  
   "action":"createOrUpdate",
   "lookupField":"email",
   "input":[  
      {  
         "email":"lead@customer.com",
         "firstName":"Sergejs",
         "lastName":"test"
      },
      {  
         "email":"lead@company.com",
         "firstName":"Sergejs",
         "lastName":"test1"
      },
      {  
         "email":"lead@mail.net",
         "firstName":"Sergejs",
         "lastName":"test2"
      }]
    }
   '

LeadId=$(curl -X GET "${baseUrl}rest/v1/leads.json?access_token=${AccessToken}&filterType=email&filterValues=${leademail}" | jq '.result | .[].id')

curl -X POST "${baseUrl}rest/v1/leads/programs/${NewProgramId}/status.json?access_token=${AccessToken}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d " {
    \"status\": \"Registered\",
    \"input\": [
        {\"id\": ${LeadId} }
    ]
}
"
```